# Ball to Ball collision - Objects stuck together

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having trouble in c#, I am trying to make a collision simulator in which the user types in values of mass, speed and direction, however when they collide they stick to eachother and not bounce off. I think this is because the program thinks the momentum of the objects is zero.

Comment: "I think this is because the program thinks the momentum of the objects is zero." Can you not throw in a break point and check?

Comment: Please read http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 6):

Though you should start by learning how to debug small programs -- see the comment on the original question -- your problem here is not just that you don't know where the bug is. The problem here is that this class is badly designed, and the design flaw is making it extremely bug prone.

The design flaw specifically is that a huge amount of the state of the class is *redundant*. The bug you are running into is that the data are *inconsistent*, which is the classic problem of redundant data. When data are redundant, any update to one of them makes it inconsistent with the rest. You then have to write code to fix the inconsistency, and that code is easy to get wrong.

To eliminate the redundancy, figure out what in your system is *fundamental*, and then only keep track of those properties. Compute the rest on-demand, rather than storing them.

In your example you have velocity, speed, direction, mass, momentum and position. You are inconsistent about how you represent them: position is a vector quantity, but is represented as individual coordinates, velocity and momentum are represented as vectors. Momentum is redundant to mass and velocity. Speed and direction are redundant to velocity. So any time you change velocity you must change speed, direction and momentum; failure to do so makes the system inconsistent, and therefore buggy.

Just don't do that.  Make read-write properties for mass, velocity and position. Make read-only properties for speed, direction and momentum.  The read-only properties compute their values from the fundamentals.

Or, if you'd rather, make mass, speed, direction and position fundamental, and compute velocity and momentum from them. Whatever. Doesn't matter. What matters is that you're not storing information that can get inconsistent.

Similarly, if you add forces and accelerations to this system as properties, compute one of them from the other. Add force as a vector property, and then compute acceleration from force and mass.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I agree with your statements here. In a specific case though I had to store calculated/derived values similar to the OP construction because of lots of reads (Yes, we measured and it made a significant difference for the UI, as it was unusable beforehand.). I never liked the design because of the myriad of derived/calculated values that needed to be kept track off to stay correct. Any suggestions for a design in this specific case?

Comment: @FrankJ: The classic performance tradeoff is increased redundancy -- that is, more memory consumed to store the same amount of information -- in exchange for improved speed. In every case its a judgment call where you have to balance the costs of the redundancy against the improvement in speed. What I find somewhat distressing is that people often fail to factor in the cost of *more bugs due to inconsistent state* in the cost of the redundancy, and instead merely concentrate on the memory burden.

Comment: @FrankJ: As for the design, basically what you are describing is a cache. There's lots of literature on what makes good and bad caches, when caches should be invalidated, measuring the cost of a cache miss, and so on. If I had a lot of them I'd be inclined to put the cache in the type system somehow.

Comment: @EricLippert: Yes, we came to the conclusion to cache eagerly to avoid cache misses and to reduce code complexity, especially in the case that a large amount of the cached values would get used anyway, so having a lazy filled cache would not be that useful. Memory was not of importance in this specific case but raw performance. So, no silver bullet here, just the same thought process we went through, and the maintainability/bug proneness remains. Thank you for the info though!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting your momentum vector in the constructor:

```
momentum.x = velocity.x * mass;
momentum.y = velocity.y * mass;
```

I suspect this is the only place you are setting it? As the velocity changes, you need to re-set your momenum vector.

That would be pretty bad practice, as it's the coders responsibility to remember to change one whenever he changes the other. Since momentum is a calculation dependent on velocity it would be better to use a "Getter", so something like this:

```
public Vector GetMomentum()
{
    return new Vector(Velocity.x*mass, Velocity.y*mass);
}
```

Or, if you want to use it like a property, use the built in getters and setters in c#:

```
public Vector Momentum
{
    get{
         return new Vector(Velocity.x*mass, Velocity.y*mass);
    }
}
```

And you can use it like you were previously with Momentum.X, and each time it will generate a new Vector. That's probably not great, but it's what fits into what code you've already got. Might be better to have use a GetXMomentum() and GetYMomentum() that does the calculation.

Comment: If the velocity.x is 6 (or 2), and mass is none zero, then the momentum cannot be zero if you implemented it like in my post. The code is multiplying Velocity by mass. 2*mass where mass=/=0 cannot equal zero. If you put a breakpoint there, check the velocity and mass values, do the math with a calculator and step out of the Get method, the momentum *will* be what you calculated.